# Property defined in scope object but not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, console.log

Why am I able to see a property inside my scope printed with `console.log()`, but directly afterwards when I try to access it it's undefined?

The following code is inside a directive's controller function:

```
console.log($scope); //a scope object with a defined "output" property
console.log($scope.output); //undefined
```

Here is the output of my scope from the first `console.log()`.

```
Scope {$id: "008", $$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$prevSibling: Scope, $$nextSibling: Scope…}
...
output: "3"
...
```

I know there is [another question asking for pretty much the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17978702/983992) but the OP is using an isolate scope with `@` for an attribute whereas I'm using `=` which won't work with `observe` as much as I know.

And then there is something else I'm a little bit confused about. Why is that even possible, isn't a `console.log()` a "snapshot" of whats given as a parameter? So how is it possible that I see a property in line 1 and in line 2 it's undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a general issue in JavaScript. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9355679/459329) very helpful.

> When you run console.log(this), you output the object itself and the
>   console links references (pointers if you like) to the inner
>   variables.

Same is valid for $scope.

Comment: Thanks, so this looks like I would have to write my own loging function which loops trough an object and console.log() all its content manually. Otherwise I will always see the "final state" in the console.

Comment: Are you setting 'output' in an asynchronous operation? I had the same problem some time ago with Backbone but I don't remember the exact solution.

Comment: Yes I am, I for now solved it with a combination of an angular promise and a setInterval which checks if the value is set. But the problem is, that when there is no value for "output" in the database it is as well undefined as when it's still loading. So I had to add a max waiting time which I hate to. But that's another topic. I'm going to accept your answer because it helped me to understand how objects are handled within console.log which was the most confusing part for me. Thanks!

Comment: if output is async it might work to deep watch, setting a true parameter such as: $scope.$watch('output', function(newdata, olddata){/*...*/}, true);