# Loading order for script inside body and using jquery ready

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser, requirejs

I've got a script inside a body tag. Problem is some code is being loaded before it is finished even though it is in a document ready block. Shouldn't the code in the ready block wait for code in the script tag to finish? Or does it only hold off until the script tag is rendered but not executed?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script data-main="script.js" src="/assets/js/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = ${fromServer};

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js:** And I expect this to wait for until script is complete...

```
$(function() {
  // access script var from here, not set yet hmmmm
});
```

I'd love to know what is going on here...

**Update:**

Okay now, here is the variable from the page

```
  require.config({
        baseUrl: '/assets/js/app',
        shim: {
            d3: {
                exports: 'd3'
            },
            underscore: {
                exports: '_',
            },
            backbone: {
                deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            uidate: {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        },
        paths: {
            d3: '../lib/d3.v3',
            jquery: '../lib/jquery-2.0.3.min',
            underscore: '../lib/underscore',
            backbone: '../lib/backbone'

        }
    });

require([...], function(...) {
  //console.log here and foo is set and good to go
  var myCollection = new MyCollection(foo);
```

inside MyCollection:

```
// define(.... {
// var coll = Backbone.Collection.extend({

initialize: function() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Looking at the console I see:

```
 {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

When I expand the object in Chrome console there are actually models in there.... strange. If I do a setTimeout inside init and `console.log(this)` again the models are set. Where is this delay of initialising the models coming from?

I've also tried just loading an array like:

```
var someColl = new MyCollection([ { ... }, { ... } ]);
```

Same problem here too.

**Update: I've tried to narrow down the scope of the problem, console.log prints an empty array here**

```
var testing = [{x:1,d:2},{x:3,d:8},{x:3,d:98}];
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
    }
});
var x = new myCollection(testing);
```

Comment: this can help you understand when document.ready is executed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: What's going on in the creation of the MyCollection object?  Is there any asynchronous code in there?  Also, `console.log(object)` can lie to you because some browsers like Chrome don't make a copy of the data at the exact instant you do `console.log(obj)` so the actual log may not show the proper data at the instant of the `console.log()` statement.  If you `console.log()` an actual value (e.g. a string or number) it will not lie or you can console.log(JSON.stringify(object)) to turn it all into a string and then it won't lie either.

Comment: Also, what library are you getting `$(function() {})` from? I assumed jQuery, but it looks like maybe you're using something else.

Comment: Okay it looks like this is related to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354932/why-is-backbone-js-returning-an-empty-array-when-accessing-models

Comment: There is no asynchronous code in the collection, just initialise and console.log(this)

Comment: @jfriend00 $(function() {}) is from backbone

Comment: Yes, it is likely that `console.log()` is lying to you which is confusing your diagnosis.  It's suggest you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this))` instead of `console.log(this)` to see what is actually there and then also change any other `console.log()` statements to only output strings, not objects.

Comment: hmmm what about using alert?

Comment: `alert()` is bad because it influences the timing of the code running.  `console.log()` with strings only is better.

Comment: still an empty array if I use stringify, gosh golly

Comment: Are you 200% sure that the models aren't filled in with an ajax call?

Comment: yes, there are no ajax calls in the models.

Comment: Then, what code fills in the models?  If they aren't there in the beginning, but are there later, obviously some code somewhere is filling them in.  It appears that you need to find out when that code that fills in the models is running.

Comment: I've defined the model attribute of the collection and the code that fills them in would just be the array I put in the constructor of MyCollection?

Comment: There is something very wrong with backbone, there is no other explanation

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question, using a very simple example I get the some empty array in this case.

Comment: Perhaps it will help you to read [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1367), [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/962) and [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/814).

Comment: @jfriend00 perhaps? why yes it does, thank you officer jfriend00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ready waits for the DOM to finish loading before calling its callback.   This will be roughly equivalent to when the `</body>` tag is parsed and everything in front of it (including any scripts) has already been parsed.  Scripts that are not marked `defer` or `async` will have already run.

It isn't entirely clear from your question what exactly your problem is, but code inside a jQuery ready block will be executed after other scripts in the `<head>` or `<body>` are executed.

If you are loading scripts asynchronously with the require.js library, then those scripts may load BEFORE or AFTER the document is ready depending upon what else is happening in the document loading.  If you need to coordinate timing with when those scripts are loaded asynchronously, then you will have to use the capabilities in the require.js library in order to know when those scripts are loaded or use document.ready in those scripts to make sure they wait for the rest of the document to be parsed.

Comment: My problem is that a variable in the script tag (inside body) is empty when accessed from the doc ready callback. I use a setTimeout in the callback and after 1 second the variable is set. So it looks like the doc ready callback doesn't wait for javascript to load in the body.

Comment: @amiawizard - please show the actual code/structure you're having trouble with.  jQuery ready DOES wait for inline `<script>` tags without defer or async attributes to execute.

Comment: on your 3rd paragraph, if the code loaded by requirejs is loaded after document is ready then shouldn't the variable from the body script be set by that time?

Comment: Code loaded by require.js has NO guaranteed load order.  It may run before or after jquery ready and, in fact, may vary from time to time.

Comment: Hmm so is it possible to load a variable from a server side language into a requirejs script?

Comment: @amiawizard - I have no idea what that last question means?

Comment: @amiawizard - What does "load a variable from a server side language" mean?

Comment: I've got data from the server I need loaded into my script

Comment: @amiawizard - it's generally easier to put data into the HTML page as script variables.  It will be available before document.ready if you do it that way.  To put data into a script file, you will have to server-side generate the script file.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what do you mean by 'put data into the HTML page as script variables'?

Comment: @amiawizard - inside an inline `<script>` tag in the HTML page, you generate variables on the server that contain your data.  Those will be then available to all scripts in the page.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but requirejs loads before the script hence my problem :( I need to access server data with a requirejs script

Comment: @amiawizard - if you place the inline script with your variables before the require.js call to load your other script, then the variable HAS to be available first.

Comment: @amiawizard - you could also use `jquery.ready` in your require.js script and all variables defined within your HTML page will be ready before the jquery.ready callback runs.

Comment: I am using: $(function() { ... });

Comment: This is strange, I've got a loop after the variable to do some parsing, a simple loop that probably take < 0.01ms yet it's not finished parsing by the time the requirejs script tries to access the variable. strange.

Comment: @amiawizard - look this is kind of pointless for me to keep trying to guess what you're real code is.  Why don't you just put your real code into your question so we can see what's really going on?

Comment: Please don't raise your voice in my presence.

Comment: @amiawizard - no voice raising here - just frustration that you won't show the actual problem.  And, frankly I'm tired of guessing.

Comment: Okay then it's your attitude, anyway I've deduced that it has nothing to do with page load ordering, the variable is set in the requirejs script BUT once I create a new backbone collection with the models, this.models is empty, 1 second later after a setTimeout, this.models has it's models. Strange indeed.

Comment: @amiawizard - where is the variable you want to use actually defined and given its value?  In an inline `<script>` in the page?  In a script loaded with require.js?  Inside a document.ready() callback from an inline script in the page?  Inside a document.ready() callback from inside the require.js script?  Somewhere else?

Comment: I think it's best I post the code, one second please.